# php separate strings with delimiters

Tags: regex

i have string for example:

```
$stringExample = "(({FAPAGE15}+500)/{GOGA:V18})"
// separete content  { }
```

I need the result to be something like that: :

```
$response = array("FAPAGE15","GOGA:V18")
```

I assume it must be something with : `preg_split` or `preg_match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the regex you need:

```
\{(.*?)\}
```

Regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/qU8eB0

PHP:

```
$str = "(({FAPAGE15}+500)/{GOGA:V18})";

preg_match_all("/\{(.*?)\}/", $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => FAPAGE15
    [1] => GOGA:V18
)
```

Working Example:

https://eval.in/92516

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative character class: `[^}]` *(all that is not a `}`)*

```
preg_match_all('~(?<={)[^}]++(?=})~', $str, $matches);

$result = $matches[0];
```

pattern details

```
~         # pattern delimiter
(?<={)    # preceded by {
[^}]++    # all that is not a } one or more times (possessive)
(?=})     # followed by }
~         # pattern delimiter
```

note: the possessive quantifier `++` is not essential to have the good result and can be replaced by `+`. You can find more informations about this feature [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).